# laravel retrieve multiple values separated by commas in a column as separate values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Hi I have a column in my database called `client_website` in my `client` database and in some cases there are multiple website links, these are separated by commas as so:

```
www.link1.com, www.link2.com, www.link3.com
```

I query the my Projects controller first as I bring

```
   @foreach ($clients as $client)   
   {{ $client->client_name }}
    {{ $client->email }}
   {{ $client->client_website }}
   @endforeach
```

It literally is printed out as below:

```
www.link1.com, www.link2.com, www.link3.com
```

and when I wrap it in a `<a>` tag it fills them the `href` with  all three links, is there anyway I can strip about the commas and spilt them into three separate entities?

Comment: You need to normalize that database (store those values separately) or keep it denormalized and _explode_ the string, turning it into a list of strings you can then iterate over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to put a second foreach in there which is sort of dirty but it does work. So you would put another foreach and then on the exploded string of websites and that will make an anchor for all websites.

Imagining these are the clients websites:

> www.link1.com, www.link2.com, www.link3.com

Your code would be like this:

```
@foreach ($clients as $client)   
   {{ $client->client_name }}
   {{ $client->email }}
      @foreach (explode(', ', $client->client_website) as $client_website)
          {{ $client_website }}
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This would output:

> Client nameClient emailwww.link1.comwww.link2.comwww.link3.com

You can then add all sorts of styling around it. It would work for any number of clients and any number of websites. Just notice that the list of websites needs to be seperated by commas **with a trailing space**.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, I recommend you define an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) in this case:

```
class Client extends Eloquent {

    public function getClientWebsiteAttribute($value)
    {
        return explode(', ', $value);
    }

}


@foreach ($clients as $client)   
   {{ $client->client_name }}
   {{ $client->email }}
      @foreach ( $client->client_website as $client_website)
          {{ $client_website }}
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```